# Webpages loaded in WKWebView does not respond to keypress events

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview, webkit, wkwebview

I want  to enable keyboard shortcuts like Cmd+c , Cmd+v to work on webpages loaded inside WKWebView, but cannot find a solution.
Webview on the other hand has methods like Copy/Paste/Cut which could be leveraged by overriding (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event method. But WKWebView does not seem to have any similar funtion.

In WebView i could do something like

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event {
NSString *s = [event charactersIgnoringModifiers];
if (s == nil)
    return;

if (([event modifierFlags] & NSDeviceIndependentModifierFlagsMask) == NSCommandKeyMask)
{
    if ([s caseInsensitiveCompare:@"a"] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        if ([[self firstResponder] respondsToSelector:@selector(selectAll:)])
            [self.contentView selectAll:self];
    }
    else if ([s caseInsensitiveCompare:@"c"] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        if ([[self firstResponder] respondsToSelector:@selector(copy:)])
            [self.contentView copy:self];
    }
    else if ([s caseInsensitiveCompare:@"v"] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        if ([[self firstResponder] respondsToSelector:@selector(paste:)])
            [self.contentView paste:self];
    }
    else if ([s caseInsensitiveCompare:@"x"] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        if ([[self firstResponder] respondsToSelector:@selector(cut:)])
            [self.contentView cut:self];
    }
    else if ([s caseInsensitiveCompare:@"z"] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        [self.contentView undo];
    }
}
else
{
    [super keyDown:event];
} }
```

In the above code self.contentView points to a WebView object

Comment: If webview doesn't react to keyboard events -> someone else is first responder. Try to find who is stealing/preventing your webview to become first responder. Also try to benefit from responder chain (who responds to e.g. copy method).